# Not able to Load Balance Socket.io request over haproxy

Tags: websocket, haproxy, internal-load-balancer

I am trying to loadbalance socket.io requests using HAProxy. The following is my configuration:

```
defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000

frontend all 0.0.0.0:8888
    mode http
    timeout client 120s

    option forwardfor
    # Fake connection:close, required in this setup.
    option http-server-close
    option http-pretend-keepalive

    acl is_socketio path_beg /socket.io

    use_backend socket-servers if is_socketio
    default_backend http-servers


backend http-servers
    balance roundrobin
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor

    # Roundrobin switching
    server node-1 172.14.2.25:8887 check
    server node-2 172.14.2.28:8887 check


backend socket-servers
    mode http
    timeout server  120s
    balance roundrobin
    # based on cookie set in header
    # haproxy will add the cookies for us
    option forwardfor
    cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
    server node1 172.14.2.25:8887 cookie node1 weight 1 maxconn 1024 check
    server node2 172.14.2.28:8887 cookie node2 weight 1 maxconn 1024 check
```

This configuration gives timeout when I try to create socket connection.

However, if I delete either on of the last two lines [**server node1 172.14.2.25:8887 cookie node1 weight 1 maxconn 1024 check** or **server node2 172.14.2.28:8887 cookie node2 weight 1 maxconn 1024 check**], the socket connects properly.

I do not understand what is wrong with the configuration. Any help will be highly appreciated.

TIA :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the configuration of **backend socket-servers**, I had to change balance roundrobin to **balance source**. That worked! :)